# How to normalize this with normalizr?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, normalizr

Consider the User object passed back:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "username": "TestUser",
  "group": 
    {
      "id": "324",
      "name": "My Group"
    }
}
```

I want to run: `normalize(user);`

And get something like this back. Is it possible? Or is it correct? I am trying to extract the group from the user, so I can place it in its own entities slot.

```
{
  result: "123",
  entities: {
    "users": { 
      "123": { 
        id: "123",
        group: "1",
        username: "TestUser
      }
    },  
    "groups": {
      "1": { "id": "324", "name": "My Group" },
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what my schemas should look like to achieve this result.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Didn't realize it was so straightforward.

```
export const group = new schema.Entity('groups', {}, {
  idAttribute: 'id'
});

export const user = new schema.Entity(
  'users',
  {
    group: group
  },
  {
    idAttribute: 'id'
  }
);
```

Comment: I think you can actually omit the `{ idAttribute: 'id' }`, normalizr assumes this